# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found | HP 15-ac054tu | BCM43142 [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, broadcom

I have install Ubuntu 18.04 on this laptop and it shows "No wi-fi adapter found".

It is a UEFI system, but my secure boot is disabled.

Output for `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: d8:5d:e2:ce:2f:bd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:91200000-91207fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 07
       serial: 30:8d:99:23:ee:0b
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:117 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:91100000-91100fff memory:91000000-91003fff
```

Output for `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
Kernel driver in use: wl
Kernel modules: wl
```

I have followed the instructions on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/60395), according to which I have installed `bcmwl-kernel-source`, but nothing seemed to have worked.

I had also installed `firmware-b43-installer` earlier, as per some other solutions, but that didn't work either.

**Edit:**

Output of `rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

**Edit2:**

The output of `rfkill list` shows that the wifi is hard blocked, which essentially means the wifi is disabled by either some bios setting, a hardware switch/button, or some key on the keyboard.

I have reset the bios and also tried different other combinations - nothing worked. There is no such hardware switch/button on the laptop. Also, there is no wifi disable option through the keyboard. And the point to note is, wifi is working on Windows. Can the hardware block be only for one operating system?

The model number of the laptop is **15-ac054tu** from HP.

**Edit3:**

I even started Ubuntu with live CD, both with Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04, and installed the driver. It still shows the same thing - hard block.

I searched over the internet with this problem - few more people with the same laptop have exactly the same problem. But couldn't find the right solution for it.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6: Added.

Comment: The driver is installed, but the adapter is hard blocked by BIOS or a hardware switch.

Comment: Is there any solution to it? Shall I also add a picture of my bios settings?

Comment: It depends on your laptop model. Try to reset bios. There is no universal solution.

Comment: But then is it possible that wifi works on Windows and not just on Ubuntu?

Comment: It may be possible if the vendor has some quirks.

Comment: I reset the bios, and also tried different options over there, but the same result. There is no physical button/switch or even keyboard shortcut to disable the wifi. The thing is the wifi is working properly in Windows. The model number of the laptop is 15-ac054tu, if that helps.

Comment: I believe it is the Airplane Mode action key.

Comment: Maybe Windows is blocking it. Do you have fast startup option enabled in Windows? If yes try disabling it otherwise try rebooting from windows into Ubuntu (usually reboots are not performed with fast startup option)

Comment: @chili555: There is an Airplane Mode key on the keyboard. But pressing that has no effect in Ubuntu.

Comment: @velix: Yes fast startup option was enabled in Windows. I disabled it and then directly restarted in Ubuntu - same no effect.

Comment: From what i have read so far, you should try to reset your bios somehow https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/TP-SMAPI/#Hardware-Reset or click on your Airplane button during boot up  or do some crazy tries like posted in here: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?18311-WiFi-hardware-blocked-RFkill-not-working&p=26333#post26333 . Also it might be possible by blacklisting some module (hp_wmi in your case i guess, check module list here https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/rfkill/) https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/wifi-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-hard-block-kernel/2146 or https://superuser.com/a/1246511/827836